# Is there a way to overwrite data using pandas.to_sql or another function?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I am writing to a table. I don't necessarily need to retain the data day to day, so I would prefer to just overwrite it. I tried using the following function assuming that it would replace the data rather than the table:

```
df.to_sql('new_test', con=connStr, if_exists='replace', index=False, schema='master')
```

The issue with this is I assume the SQL language on the backend dropped the table rather than truncated the data within. I suspect this because it completely scrubbed by table of all constraints and changed a datetime column to a timestamp column. Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "truncated the data within"? Using `if_exists = 'replace'` means the existing table will be dropped and replaced by the table generated from df.

Comment: In SQL, you can use the "truncate" command to delete the data contained within the table you declare. Without reading into documentation, I had expected it to delete the data within and replace it with the new data, simply an overwrite, which is my goal. But yes, you are correct in the functionality of 'replace'. Trying to find a way to overwrite rather than drop the table.